# Dynamically colspan not manage properly work

Tags: html, css

[This error I have got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vceZl.png)
This is a dynamic table design I didn't manage colspan in next tr. Can any one resolve it. The colspan is dynamically added colsapn divide perfectly and each row has same colspan data but design and divide not perfect.

```
<div class="container">
        <section class="mt-5">
           
            <table class="binary" style="width:50%">
                <colgroup>
                    <col span="1286">
                </colgroup>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td colspan="1019" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('1', '1')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1019</td>
                    <td colspan="267" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('2', '1')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">267</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="1002" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('1', '2')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1002</td>
                    <td colspan="17" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('2', '2')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">17</td>
                    <td colspan="267" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('4', '2')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">267</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="995" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('1', '3')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">995</td>
                    <td colspan="7" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('2', '3')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">7</td>
                    <td colspan="17" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('4', '3')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">17</td>
                    <td colspan="267" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('8', '3')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">267</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="994" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('1', '4')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">994</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('2', '4')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1</td>
                    <td colspan="7" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('4', '4')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">7</td>
                    <td colspan="17" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('8', '4')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">17</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('15', '4')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1</td>
                    <td colspan="266" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('16', '4')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">266</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="994" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('1', '5')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">994</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('4', '5')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1</td>
                    <td colspan="7" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('8', '5')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">7</td>
                    <td colspan="17" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('16', '5')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">17</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('29', '5')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1</td>
                    <td colspan="266" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('32', '5')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">266</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="958" style="background:Green; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('1', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">958</td>
                    <td colspan="36" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('2', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">36</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('8', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1</td>
                    <td colspan="7" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('16', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">7</td>
                    <td colspan="17" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('32', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">17</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('58', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1</td>
                    <td colspan="266" style="background:Black; color:#fff;" class="" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="postdata('64', '6')" data-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">266</td>
                </tr>


            </tbody></table>
    
    </section>
    </div>
```

[I want exactly like this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SMh.png)
I am tried multiple ul, li, div but it's not manage design.

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. Running your code make it look as in the image

Comment: Can you please relook my question @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I think you cannot do this because there seems to be a limit of 1000 on a colspan. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923717/how-to-do-colspan-for-more-than-1000-columns-in-a-html-table Does that answer your question sufficiently?

Comment: Perhaps if you share the use case (i.e. real data and semantics), we can think of an alternative to colspans larger that 1000, cause indeed it isn't allowed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan